# Jquery ui Sortable in right diagonal

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery UI sortable, where I am changing DIV's, is a problem that occurs when pressing a div diagonally right, the movement of my div going forward, but the div I'm on top, stays in place, that can not occur. Should have gone forward.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uzabV/1/

Comment: i added content to the divs so it's more visable what is going on, http://jsfiddle.net/uzabV/1/ i seem to be able to drag right diagonal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I could see with your example that might have caused your concern is that it is sometimes a little difficult to get the swap to happen. If you change the `tolerance` from `intersect` to `pointer`, i think it might help. try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uzabV/2/

Comment: The problem is this, a difficulty occurs (delayed) in div that should change. This does not occur in the left diagonal, but the diagonal right occurred. I have not found the solution still.

Comment: I'm not seeing the delay, on my jsfiddle, how wide do you have the container (how many rows are your divs)? What number are you dragging to what number? What browser are you using?

Comment: Note that if I drag the 4 in half the 2. The 3 descends to the place of 4, but the 2 do not go to the place the 3.
Now, if you try to put the number 5 in 1. It is noticed that there is a big difference

Comment: When I have the width so that there are 3 rows, and I drag the 4 to the 2... the 4 ->(goes to where) 2(was), the 2 -> 3, the 3 -> 4. This seems to be what I would expect to happen. When I drag 5 to 1... 5 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5. This also is what I expect to happen.